# Truth table with 4 variables alternative?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was wondering for this question:

**1.3 Formalise the following argument in propositional logic, and decide whether it is logically correct. Explain your answer.**

If it is raining and the birds are singing, then Joe is not happy.

It is not a good day and it is raining.

If the birds are singing and Joe is happy, then it is a good day.

Therefore, -----------------------------------------------------

If Joe is not happy, then the birds are not singing.

The method that the solution uses is constructing a truth table with 4 propositions and it finds that the argument is not logically correct which makes sense. We need to find a situation where all the premises are true but the conclusion is true.

> Is there any other method of proving this other than having to construct a truth table which is tedious for 4 variables?

Comment: In this particular case, statement $2$ fixes the truth values of $2$ of the $4$ propositions, which means you have only $4$ cases to consider not $16$.

Answer (score 1):

> If it is raining and the birds are singing, then Joe is not happy.

$$r\land s\to p$$

> It is not a good day and it is raining.

$$\lnot q\land r$$

> If the birds are singing and Joe is happy, then it is a good day.

$$s\land p\to q$$

> Therefore: If Joe is not happy, then the birds are not singing.

$$\therefore p\to\lnot s$$

Well, when we value the second premise as true, then we assert $q$ is false.  So when we also value the third premise as true, we cannot value both $p$ and $s$ as true (because that would imply that $q$ is true, a contradiction); so therefore ...